# recorrer un array de objetos con ciclo for javascript

Tags: javascript

Bien, necesito hacer esto con un ciclo **`for`** 
con el **`foreach`** si lo se usar pero quiero hacerlo con **`for`**, si en caso de que no se pueda hacer por alguna razón, agradecería me expliquen el por que.

```js
var arreglo=[{valor: 100}, {valor: 200}, {valor: 300}, {valor: 400}, {valor: 500}, {valor: 600}, {valor: 700}, {valor: 800}]

// esto es un ejemplo mas o menos de lo que quiero hacer pero con un ciclo for
cadena = `` 
arreglo.forEach(element => {
    cadena += `<input type="number" value="${element.valor}"><br>`
});
cadena += ``

document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = cadena;
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

lo que estaba intentado:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
cadena += `<input type="number" value="${arreglo.valor[i]}"><br>`}
```

Comment: Puedes compartir como lo estas haciendo con el ciclo `for`?

Comment: @MerlingSamuelSobalvarro, claro ya lo agrego, aunque ahora que vi tu código, jajaja me da risa el mio no lo había pensado bien.

Comment: Espero te ayude! Saludos :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funciona correctamente con el ciclo `for`.

```js
var arreglo=[{valor: 100}, {valor: 200}, {valor: 300}, {valor: 400}, {valor: 500}, {valor: 600}, {valor: 700}, {valor: 800}]

let cadena = ``
for (let i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
  const { valor } = arreglo[i]
  
  cadena += `<input type="number" value="${valor}"><br>`
}

cadena += ``

document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = cadena;
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo si me sirve para lo que necesito.